# WordPress for a business catalog site

Tags: cms, seo, customization, listing

I am completely noob with WordPress so I apologize in advance if my questions sounds completely stupid.

**Background**

I have a small [business catalog site](http://venhawk.com) that I wrote long ago in plain HTML. Now I want to add some SEO and improve the design therefore I am looking to use a CMS for easy content management.

**Questions**

- Is WordPress a right choice for my requirements? Is it only for blogging or can be used for any kind of site? (corporate, portfolio, catalog, personal info etc.)
- Will I need some kind of plugins for SEO and displaying product catalog?
- How can I remove the blog look (posts/dates/comments etc.) from the site?

Any hints/links/insights will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is WordPress a right choice for my
>   requirements? Is it only for blogging
>   or can be used for any kind of site?
>   (corporate, portfolio, catalog,
>   personal info etc.)

WordPress can absolutely be used for any kind of site. But note that while things like post and pages are ready out of the box and simple to use, it takes some additional development if you want to implement your own types of content with more complex data ([Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)).

> Will I need some kind of plugins for
>   SEO and displaying product catalog?
>
> How can I remove the blog look (posts/dates/comments etc.) from the site?

There is number of highly functional and free SEO plugins available. [WordPress SEO by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) gets a lot of traction lately.

Displaying content mostly depends on theme. There is an insane amount of themes available (starting with [official repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) and beyond), but as above - it may take some development if you need to implement something more complex.

Answer (score 2):

I'll echo everything that @Rarst said and I'll add links to two of my answers that might help you:

- [**Tips for using WordPress as a CMS?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187)
- [**Implementing a CrunchBase.com Clone using WordPress?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381/implementing-a-crunchbase-com-clone-using-wordpress/386#386)

If you don't want to do it yourself I'll recommend a theme I just purchased for a similar project from WooTheme's called Listings.

- [**WooTheme's Listings**](http://www.woothemes.com/2010/12/listings/)

It's not free but it solves so many issues you'll have to address I think it'd be money well spent. Here's a screenshot of their blog post about the theme *(since I like to include pictures in my answers :-):*

[image: WooThemes Listings Theme]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/http___www.woothemes.com_2010_12_listings_-20110108-123022.png))</sub>

Comment: Damn, I can't even estimate how much work something that fancy took... Every time I see something that functional done in WP I feel like I still hadn't even scratched surface.

Comment: @Rarst - Yeah. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel by the way, if you have enough practical experience with it already - could you please write up on this one in [WordPress frameworks and parent themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes)? I think it's extremely interesting one.

Comment: @Rarst - I just started using it and I've had other client work and since it's my own project I've not had the time to dive in. Later...

Comment: @craftsman - Glad it was helpful.