# Which is the simplest theme for Wordpress to use it as your base?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am building a new theme for my site, and I was wondering which is the simplest/lite theme with only the files needed like single.php index.php author.php and so on.

I have read about wordpress themes and what files I have to include but I will have to code the default functions like wp-comments if I start from here.

So I am looking for a lite theme to start over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opinions and recommendations on the best barebones base theme](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/opinions-and-recommendations-on-the-best-barebones-base-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asked a few times, this link has some good answers [Opinions and recommendations on the best barebones base theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/opinions-and-recommendations-on-the-best-barebones-base-theme)

Comment: I'm not certain that "barebones" is what the OP is after. I am inferring that he wants a fully functional, usable-out-of-the-box Theme, but a Theme that doesn't have too much complexity. I could be wrong - which is why I'm digging for more specific requirements. :)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. Something like Kubrick or Default but on 3.1

Comment: @chip agreed, after reading the OP's latest comments it does indeed seem he is looking for a lite option rather than using a barebones theme as a launchpad for his project...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either TwentyTen or TwentyEleven as great, basic starter Themes. Both include a few nice bells and whistles, but for the most part are straight-forward, simple Themes.

However, can you clarify a little more specifically what you're looking for? For example, you mention that you are looking for a Theme that includes "only the files needed", but then list two entirely unnecessary files, `single.php` and (especially) `author.php`.

Do you want a Theme that is easy to modify? Easy to override with a Child Theme? Easy to grok the underlying code? What are your *specific* needs?

**EDIT**

That's what I mean about being more *specific*:

1. How are *we* supposed to know what is "useless" for *you*?
2. What Theme template files do you consider to be "necessary"? Especially considering that only 3 files are truly "necessary" - `index.php`, `style.css`, and `comments.php` - if you consider other template files to be "necessary", then you'll have to communicate your needs more clearly.
3. What "main functions" do you want the Theme to include?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am in need of a theme that does not have any useless for me extra backend panels, and have the necessary theme files including the "unnecessary", like single and author. It should have the main functions to work it as is.

Comment: I have saw a list of those themes and wrote your comment on Roots about renaming for example wp-content/ to assets and so on. I totally agree with you and is one reason I will not going to use this.

Answer (score -1):

Try the "Simplest" Theme.
http://trevorturk.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/new-wordpress-theme-simplest/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).