# A theme that follows all the best practices to learn from?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Are there any good themes that follows all the best practices, to the letter, that I can refer to will creating my themes?

Comment: Just create a child-theme based on the 2011-theme (the current WP default).

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what the theme building "best practices" are. Usually, you see mentions of what not to do.  Is there a list of "10 Things to Do When Building A WordPress Theme"?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'best practices' it can be very subjective. Clean semantic code, lightweight, using proper template tags, etc are all best practices. So looking at a theme like twentyeleven is a great start. If it ships with WP, it must be a good example of what they currently consider best practices.

Comment: I would consider the WPORG Theme Repository [Theme Review Guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review) to be (currently) the most comprehensive list of "best practices" for publicly released Themes.

Comment: Also, leaving this as a comment, rather than an answer, so I don't appear to be spamming/plugging my own Theme: I [developed the Oenology Theme *specifically* to serve as a tool to help other developers](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/oenology) learn to develop WordPress Themes, and to serve as an example of implementation of all best practices.

Comment: @Chip Bennett  - There you go, brother. [The Theme Review Guidelines](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review) are just what I was looking for. You should post your response as an answer.

Comment: @Ray Mitchell: well, the Theme Review Guidelines are an example of "best practices", but that in itself doesn't really answer the OP's question. If someone asked a question "what are WordPress Theme development best practices?" then I would certainly post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

WordPress's [Twenty Ten](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyten) and [Twenty Eleven](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven) (which both ship with Core as of this writing) are most "official" themes. There's also the recently released "underscores" or ["_s" theme](https://github.com/Automattic/_s) from Automattic. Twenty Twelve will come out with WordPress 3.5 and is made by The Theme Foundry, which I think quite highly of.

There are lots and lots of good themes, but I'd recommend starting with the ones written by the people who make WordPress.

===
EDIT: If you want to modify Twenty Ten or Twenty Eleven, make sure to do it using [a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that your changes aren't lost when those themes receive updates. However, _s is intended to be a starter theme and NOT a child theme, so for that one, take all the files and turn them into your own theme.

===
EDIT II: And of course, now there's [Twenty Twelve](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [starter "blank" themes](http://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20blank%20theme) to play with. Personally I'm quite happy with the [Toolbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/toolbox) theme, it's minimalist, semantic, HTML5 theme with all the default WP pages (if that's what you consider "best practice")

Comment: I would **NEVER** start **ANY** search for WordPress Themes via Google search. (Though, I will admit that the results for your query string appear to be *hugely* improved from a few months ago.) Note: there are related WPSE questions regarding "starter" Themes; e.g. [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21356/which-is-the-simplest-theme-for-wordpress-to-use-it-as-your-base) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/opinions-and-recommendations-on-the-best-barebones-base-theme). They'd be a great place to start.