# Wordpress framework

Tags: framework

It's not a question that can be answer wit a single BEST answer, but i like to know wich framework outthere could solve most of de problem of creating a site from PSD to html. What i am looking to is. HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, SEO build in, Drag and drop interface, Font replacement (cufont), microformat, responsive, mobile friendly, 960px wide, boilerplate.

This list of next generation framework feature could be longer, but wich framework do you suggest me, that include the most of the request above...

BTW, i code psd to wp theme from hand coding, or use headway.... both situation not perfect neither fast !. I have heard a lot of good thing about genesis... but never tried it !

--

As being said, it's not a clear question... here is what i like to know. What interface/addin you could install OVER wordpress basic installation to make it a nive platform to convert a PSD to a live site, with the lates technology like html5 and jquery.. that ca be view on mobile device without too much fuss

Comment: Your question is very vague: A list of … buzz words, no clear goal. I’m tempted to close it as a duplicate of [WordPress frameworks and parent themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3725/73). Please refine your question. Thanks.

Comment: I am going to edit this answer. The spelling and grammar needs a little refinement.

Comment: @Dwayne Your edits are _massive_ and may change the meaning of the question. That’s why I rejected the edit, sorry.

Comment: No worries Toscho. Yeah I was being a bit interpretive, but part of me knew the question would probably be closed anyway. No hard feelings Toscho.

Comment: i tried !, and got a good link from toscho, that better than nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware and based on interpretation of your heavily indecipherable question (no disrespect intended) you are asking for a plugin or framework that you can install in Wordpress that will allow you to visually convert a PSD into a Wordpress theme. As far as I know there isn't such a thing in any form of Wordpress plugin or framework that will do the work for you.

There are programs out there and online services that allow you to upload PSD files and define particular regions and it'll create a theme for you, not sure if they're all free though and I doubt the time you'd spend uploading a PSD and defining the spots to convert would save you any time.

Any tool that takes something and automises it (even partially) will have its downsides and you might find yourself detangling improper auto generated code you have no understanding on.

Frameworks like Genesis are great because they come with support for custom options pages and are generally very easy to use. Regardless of what boilerplate or framework you use, you'll still need to cut the PSD up yourself, the framework doesn't do the heavy lifting for you in the front-end department.