# If you were to start using a Wordpress framework today, which one would you use?

Tags: theme-development, themes, framework, genesis-theme-framework

Today, there are a [ton of WP frameworks out there](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/10/a-comparison-of-leading-wordpress-theme-frameworks/). When I first started using one, there were only 3 or 4, and I picked [Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com). My (yearly) hybrid license expired again, so I decided to take a look around.

There are way more options now. I am not concerned with drag and drop child theme building capacity. I dont mind paying. Most important is standards compliance, HTML5, SEO, mobile version and an active community. Decent availability of child themes is a plus. We dont always have the resources/desire to build everything from scratch.

I already know [Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com), and I am taking a like to [Genesis](http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis). **What are your experiences with the frameworks out there and which one would you recommend?**

PS: Sorry, there is no need to cite [Thesis](http://diythemes.com/): I have an aversion to the way it is marketed. Please dont try to convince me otherwise, ok?

Comment: Close-voted as **not constructive**: "*This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*". Also, did you even *try* to [**search the site for Theme-framework related questions**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=theme+frameworks)?

Comment: Yes, I did the search, but a good recommendation is suited to one's needs. I didnt find anyone with needs like mine that had the same question here. But I agree, it will be hard to nail an answer down for this one.

Comment: See [WordPress frameworks and parent themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes) for an overview. Your question doesn't have a real answer, it is a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), so I have to close it.

Comment: @toscho Maybe this question could also be turned into community wiki mode. The one you point to is eons old, relatively speaking. it doesnt mention one single HTML5 framework.

Comment: @Gaia Then just add missing frameworks over there. I see no reason to create another, similar question that will be out of date soon too. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55997/145551

Comment: Ok. I think this one is a case for Quora, not Stack...

Answer (score 3):

Please check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/wordpress-frameworks-and-parent-themes).  Its already contain 10+ answers about wordpress frameworks.

Comment: Sorry, that Q is eons old, relatively speaking. it doesnt mention one single HTML5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own mini framework which is basically child theme of the standard TwentyTen theme. Most of the frameworks are too complicated - they use specific shortcodes and other things that may lock you in.

Playing with child theme will make you really learn something useful that can be applied to any theme.